# Native iOS icon sets

Tags: icons, ios, native-app

I've always found designing natively for iOS tricky - Google seems to just have everything there for you to look through and design exactly the same.

Whereas the Apple Human Interface Guidelines still seem to add confusion for me and I end up with more questions that I originally started with!

Take Googles Material Icons page for instance - is there anything similar at all for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Take Googles Material Icons page for instance - is there anything
>   similar at all for iOS?

Yes there is. Apple makes a difference between app icons and system icons, which are more similar to those listed at Material Design, just take a look to [**System Icons (iOS 12 and Earlier)**](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/) .

From iOS13, the icons change to [**SF Symbols**](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/), with 1500+ icons in different weights from *ultra light* to *heavy*. There are a few common listed there, but you can download the [**SF Symbols app**](https://developer.apple.com/design/downloads/SF-Symbols.dmg) for free to browse all of them

Of course, you can just do a search for custom icons for iOS, there are many resources, but if you want the native set, they're listed on the pages mentioned above

Comment: Thanks for this! I had seen this SF Symbols, but I didn't actually realise it was an app! (Doh!) - but I've got it working now, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For icons, I generally use the IonIcon library (https://ionicons.com/).  There are other third party collections out there, but this library was designed for use in mobile apps. A new version is in the works to update them to iOS 13.

I have never seen a page like that in the Apple HIG site.